# Creating a filter for an added column in a table CGridView (Yii)

Tags: php, yii, filter, cgridview

So I'm kinda new to Yii, and in my project, I needed to add and extra column containing data from another table in the database. I need to implement the filtering for this column too, and  from what I've read, I need to add it to the search function in the model, but I can't seem to pull it off. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

This is the view (the added column is 'areaReservada')

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'reserva-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'itemsCssClass'=>"table table-striped",
    'pager'=>array("htmlOptions"=>array("class"=>"pagination")),
    //'ajaxupdate'=>false,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
                'name'=>'idreserva',
                'header'=>'<p style="color: black">Número de reserva</p>',
                //'value'=>'$data->area->nombre',
                //'type'=>'raw',
                'value'=>'$data->idreserva',
                //'filter'=>Costoarea::getAreas(),
            ),
        //'idreserva',
        array(
                'name'=>'fecha',
                'header'=>'<p style="color: black">Fecha de Reserva</p>',
                'value'=>'$data->fecha',
                //'type'=>'raw',
                //'value'=>'$model->estadoReserva_idestadoReserva',
                //'filter'=>Costoarea::getAreas(),
            ),
        //'fecha',
        array(
                'name'=>'areaReservada',
                'header'=>'<p style="color: black">Área Reservada</p>',
                'value'=>'$data->getArea($data->idreserva)',
                //'type'=>'raw',
                //'value'=>'$model->estadoReserva_idestadoReserva',
                //'filter'=>Costoarea::getAreas(),
            )));?>
```

This area my search function and the rules set in my model

> ```
>   public function search()    {
>
>
>   $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
>
>   $criteria->compare('idreserva',$this->idreserva);
>   $criteria->compare('fecha',$this->fecha,true);
>   $criteria->compare('motivo',$this->motivo,true);
>   $criteria->compare('monto',$this->monto);
>   $criteria->compare('responsable',$this->responsable,true);
>   $criteria->compare('estadoReserva_idestadoReserva',$this->estadoReserva_idestadoReserva);
>   $criteria->compare('usuario_idusuario',$this->usuario_idusuario);
>
>
>   return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
>       'criteria'=>$criteria,));   }
>
>
>   public function rules()     {
>
>       return array(array('estadoReserva_idestadoReserva,usuario_idusuario', 'required'),
>
>       array('estadoReserva_idestadoReserva, usuario_idusuario','numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),array('monto','numerical'),
>       array('motivo, responsable', 'length', 'max'=>45),
>       array('fecha', 'safe'),
>
>       array('idreserva, fecha, motivo, monto, responsable,estadoReserva_idestadoReserva, usuario_idusuario', 'safe',> 'on'=>'search'), );     
>       }
> ```

Comment: Do you have the column idarea (or similar) in your model?

Answer (score 0):

To filter using new added extra column, you have to make following changes in your model as:

```
// For example, new extra column is 'areaReservada'.
public $areaReservada;

public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('areaReservada', 'safe'),
    );
}

public function relations() {
    return array(
        'other_model' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'OtherModel', 'foreign_key'),
    );
}

public function search() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->with = array('other_model');

    $criteria->compare('idreserva', $this->idreserva);
    $criteria->compare('fecha', $this->fecha, true);
    $criteria->compare('motivo', $this->motivo, true);
    $criteria->compare('monto', $this->monto);
    $criteria->compare('responsable', $this->responsable, true);
    $criteria->compare('estadoReserva_idestadoReserva', $this->estadoReserva_idestadoReserva);
    $criteria->compare('usuario_idusuario', $this->usuario_idusuario);
    $criteria->compare('other_model.column', $this->areaReservada); // Compare value contained in 'areaReservada' with column of other model to be filtered

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
      'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));   
}
```

Hope this help you! Let me know if there is any concern from this.